# Word and phrase search on multiple fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I'd like to search documents using Python through ElasticSearch. I am looking for documents which contains word and/or phrase in any one of three fields.

```
GET /my_docs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Ford \"lone star\"",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "description",
        "news_content"
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "-1",
      "operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

In the above query, I'd like to get documents whose title,  description, or news_content contain "Ford" and "lone star" (as a phrase).

However, it seems that it does not consider "lone star" as a phrase. It returns documents with "Ford", "lone", and "star".

Comment: could you please go through my answer and let me know if you have further clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to reproduce your issue and solved it using the REST API of Elasticsearch as I am not familiar with the python syntax and glad you provided your search query in JSON format, and I built my solution on top of it.

### Index def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "description" :{
                "type" : "text"
            },
            "news_content" : {
                "type" : "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Sample docs

```
{
  "title" : "Ford",
  "news_content" : "lone star", --> note this matches your criteria
  "description" : "foo bar"
}

{
  "title" : "Ford",
  "news_content" : "lone",
  "description" : "star"
}
```

### Search query you are looking for

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [ --> note this, both clause must match
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "ford",
                        "fields": [
                            "title",
                            "description",
                            "news_content"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "lone star",
                        "fields": [
                            "title",
                            "description",
                            "news_content"
                        ],
                        "type": "phrase" --> note `lone star` must be phrase
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Result contains just one doc from sample

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so_phrase",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.9527341,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Ford",
          "news_content": "lone star",
          "description": "foo bar"
        }
      }
    ]
```